# Запись и чтение treemap

Tags: java, map

Встретилась с таким вопросом: Пишу TreeMap < Class , Integer >, где ключами являются объекты класса.
У меня есть класс CharasteristicsOfMusic, а в нем конструктор

```
public class CharasteristicsOfMusic implements  Comparable<CharasteristicsOfMusic>{
    String anArtist;
    String composition;
    int year;

public CharasteristicsOfMusic(String anArtist, String composition, int year) {
        this.anArtist = anArtist;
        this.composition = composition;
        this.year = year;
    }
@Override
    public int compareTo(CharasteristicsOfMusic charasteristicsOfMusic) {

        if(charasteristicsOfMusic.getAnArtist()==this.getAnArtist() && charasteristicsOfMusic.getComposition() == this.getComposition()) return 0;
        if(charasteristicsOfMusic.getYear()>this.getYear()) return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Само задание состоит в том, чтобы записать из файла/ в файл TreeMap < CharasteristicsOfMusic, Integer> 
Например, файл

```
ExArtirs1 ExComposition1 ExYear1 : 1
ExArtirs1 ExComposition1 ExYear1 : 2
ExArtirs1 ExComposition1 ExYear1 : 3
должен распарсится в TreeMap < CharasteristicsOfMusic, Integer> , и наоборот.
```

Пробовала так:

```
public void WriteFile( TreeMap<CharasteristicsOfMusic, Integer> map, String filename) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        for (Map.Entry<CharasteristicsOfMusic, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            bf.write(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
            bf.newLine();

        }
    }
```

Но при этом ничего не просходит
Подскажите пожалуйста , как это можно решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java каждый открытый ресурс должен быть обязательно закрыт, для того, чтобы запись/чтение отработали как задумано.

В вашем же случае, вы открываете поток записи в файл, кладёте данные в буфер в оперативной памяти, и тут программа завершается, не успев переместить данные на жёсткий диск. Чтобы всё заработало, нужно просто добавить после окончания записи вызов метода `close()`:

```
    public static void writeFile(TreeMap<CharasteristicsOfMusic, Integer> map, String filename) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    for (Map.Entry<CharasteristicsOfMusic, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        bf.write(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        bf.newLine();
    }
    bf.close();
}
```

Можно обойтись и без явного вызова `close()`: в Java 7 ввели формат записи, называемый `try-with-resources`. Тут мы открываем ресурс в круглых скобках, и программа закрывает его автоматически после использования:

```
    public static void writeFile(TreeMap<CharasteristicsOfMusic, Integer> map, String filename) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    try (BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        for (Map.Entry<CharasteristicsOfMusic, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            bf.write(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
            bf.newLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: не обязательно вызывать `close`, достаточно вызвать `flush`

Comment: Cпасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

С чтением из файла разобралась так, открыта к доработке/ новым идеям.

```
  public void read() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileName = "infoMusic.txt";
        System.out.println("\nLoading contacts into " + fileName + "...");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        for (Map.Entry product : tm.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(product.getKey() + " : " + product.getValue());
            writer.println(product.getKey() + ", " + product.getValue());
        }
        writer.close(); // Important: close the io resource after using it.
    }
```